# 504 XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism not supported

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail-api

Using Google OAUTH service to send an email using nodemailer. It works in the local environment (windows), but not in production (AlmaLinux OS).However, gave me an "504 XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism not supported" error in production environment.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**Code:**

```
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: "gmail",
            auth: {
                  type: "OAuth2",
                  user: "test@gmail.com", 
                  clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRECT,
                  refreshToken: process.env.GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN,
                  accessToken: googleToken
            },
            tls: {
               rejectUnauthorized: true
            },
            
          })
          const mailData = {
            from: "test@gmail.com",
            to: emailDetails.to,
            subject: emailDetails.subject,
          // text: emailDetails.message,
            html: `<div>${emailDetails.message}</div>
                  
            `
          }
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(mailData));
          transporter.sendMail(mailData, function (err, info) {
            if(err){
              console.log(err)  
              res.send({status: 0, message:"Error occured", errors: [{code: "", message: err}]});
            } else {
              console.log(info)
              res.send({status: 1, message:"successfully send an email", errors: []});
            }
            transporter.close();
          })
         
        }).catch(error => console.log(error));
        
    ][1]
```

Error message output here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn4nR.png)